# What do you return in the method with Webclient non-blocking call?

Tags: java, webclient

I am trying to understand how I should write WebClient api calls for my method. Here is a simple example:

```
private String save(String body) {
   WebClient client = Webclient.create(saveUrl);
   Mono<String> response = client.post()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(this.getFormInserter(body))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
   responseText.doOnNext(response -> //log successful save message).subscribe();
   return ??; // what do I return here?
```

I know that when I successfully completes the request, it will do `//log successful save message`, which is the desired behavior.

However, what is common practice for the `save` method that I have? I am used to return some string value back to the caller, maybe success/failure message, or for other cases, I return body in order to process further.

For more practical example that I am currently working on, I call WebClient to get an access token, and use it in another WebClient to actually save the body like this:
TokenService:

```
    @Override
    public String getToken(String message) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(tokenUrl);
        Mono<String> responseText = client.post()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(this.getFormInserter())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .retry(3);
        responseText.doOnNext(response -> saveService.save(message, getToken(response))).subscribe();
        return // what to return?
    }

    private String getToken(String responseBody) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody, JsonObject.class);
        return jsonObject.get(ACCESS_TOKEN_FIELD).toString();
    }
```

SaveService:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(String message, String accessToken) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(saveUrl)
                .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
                })
                .build();
        client.post().body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(message), String.class));
        return null; //do i need to return something?
    }
```

How I understand WebClient non-blocking call is that it should, as non-blocking suggest, not block the thread. Meaning, WebClient calls that I created should have their own flow until save (since I need token). However, what should I do with the caller who calls the method?

My first approach before knowing WebClient was to make rest call in TokenService, get the token, pass it to SaveService and save it. Now, TokenService(will have to change name) is getting the token and save it.

Is my current approach okay? and what should I return for caller? Should it return anything? It seems like the caller won't know if call was successful or failure... Not sure if I should log anything besides I tried to save it?

Answer (score 0):

After the "getToken" method is called successfully, it should return to tell the user that you have successfully obtained the Token and do not need to wait for the execution of the "save" method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).